# How do I stop my 2 year old Siamese from soiling my bed and my nan's bed (on occasion, the dog's bed)?

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training, anxiety, stress

I got Sunny from a breeder almost 2 years ago. He was approximately 14 weeks old. For the first week or so he continued to soil on the bed, and refused to go in the litter box. After some swapping around with different litters, we finally found one he liked and he stopped soiling...for a little while.

It is not every day, or even every week; but seemingly out of the blue, Sunny will go and soil on my bed (and usually for 2-3 days, if I don't close the bedroom door). He doesn't wee...just poo.

This has been happening on and off for the two years. I've tried loads of different things (as I believe he may be suffering from anxiety). I have 3 litter boxes - all are kept in a clean (but not too clean) condition and are scattered around the house (I even kept one in my room for a time to see if this would deter Sunny from soiling on my bed...to no avail).

Apart from me constantly having to wash my sheets (which takes time and water), it wouldn't bother me TOO much. However, if MY door is closed he will go and soil on my nan's bed. Even though I tell my nan to keep her door closed, she is 86 and is forgetful... then she gets cranky at me because MY cat has "sh**" on her bed.

I have tried reprimanding Sunny (sometimes not very well I am sorry to say), I've tried ignoring the behaviour and nothing seems to be working. I have got to the point where I just close my door, and if I forget, and leave it open and he poos on my bed, we'll that's my fault. But I can't have him soiling my nan's bed every other day (or the dog's bed, which does happen on occasion).

Sometimes this happens in a small time slot where Nan has woken up to go to the toilet, not closed her bedroom door, and while she is in the toilet, Sunny soils on her bed.

Sunny is also desexed. He is an indoor cat, but does have access to the backyard when I am present - we also have a cat fence put up to stop him escaping. As I mentioned before...I THINK this is an anxiety reaction, but I don't know what from. He and the dog are besties and get along very well. Sunny is a one-person cat, and will only go to other people if I am not present. 
He gets fed good food (both wet and dry) and keeps a regular schedule.

He has recently started soiling again, over the last 2 days, which is what has prompted this post. Firstly on Nan's bed, then on mine yesterday afternoon (which he hasn't done before - he usually soils in the morning). I am at my wit's end. I love my Lil Man and would never get rid of him because of his 'dirtiness', however I am getting increasingly frustrated and a little upset by the whole deal. My mum is about ready to disown him. I feel guilty that I have brought such a 'naughty' cat into the house.

How can I get my cat to poo in his litter box?

Answer (score 2):

For us, what worked was confining the cat (with the litter box of course), to an area with no access to any beds/bedrooms. For us, this meant the cement-floored portion of our basement. We spent a couple of weeks like this, then tried again for a longer period when it failed (with visits and snuggles throughout both confinements of course).

Another thing that helped with potty compliance was removing the lids from the litter boxes (if you have a lidded box). I notice that without the lids, the cats sort of "hang over" the edges while doing their business or covering their business. A box with a lid (or the box itself) may just be too cramped for his digging/pooping style.

Re: anxiety, a vet visit is called for. There are anti-anxiety pills for cats. Don't feel bad about a little pharmaceutical help for your furry friend. If your cat is treat oriented, pill pockets work wonders.

Also couple of experienced ladies from a rescue advised that many cats find dried lavender calming, if you want to try something more natural first. I never tried that personally, as I find the smell overwhelming.